# cannot use nil value as a return of type struct

Tags: go

I have this function which is supposed to query database and return an `article` if found, and nil if the article is not found:

```
func GetArticleBySlug(slug string) (model.Article, error) {
    var err error
    var article model.Article
    err = database.SQL.Get(&article, "SELECT * FROM article WHERE slug=? LIMIT 1", slug)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil, err //<- Problem here
    }
    return article, nil
}
```

Where `Article` is a struct defined in `model` package.

I get this error:

> cannot use nil as type model.Article in return argument

How can I fix this?

Comment: `nil` is only a valid value for pointer, slices, and maps. You cannot have a `nil` struct value, for example.

Comment: So what should I return instead, when the struct is not found?

Comment: Typically in a function like this your error return would be e.g. `return model.Article{}, err` to return an empty struct.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Adrian. Please answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`nil` is only a valid value for pointer, slices, and maps. You cannot have a `nil` struct value, for example.

Typically in a function like this your error return would be e.g.

```
return model.Article{}, err
```

to return an empty struct.

Comment: `nil` is also valid for interfaces

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return the nil in case of error, update your function to this

```
    func GetArticleBySlug(slug string) (*model.Article, error) {
    var err error
    article := new(model.Article)
    err = database.SQL.Get(&article, "SELECT * FROM article WHERE slug=? LIMIT 1", slug)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil, err //<- Problem here
    }
    return article, nil
}
```